# Move constructor for polymorphic members with back reference

Tags: c++, state, move-semantics

I implemented the State pattern which also includes references to the subject class.

```
class State {
public:
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;

protected:
    State(Subject& s) : subject_{s} {}

private:
    Subject& subject_;
};

class StateA : public State {
public: 
    StateA(Subject& s, Subject& target) : State(s), target_{t} {}

    void doStuff() override { /* implementation requiring subject_ */ }  

private:
    Subject& target_;
};

class Subject {
public:
    void doStuff() { state_->doStuff(); }
    State* state_;
};
```

When I want to use a collection of subjects in a container that requires move-semantics (like `std::vector`), the default move-constructor is not sufficient since the moved state stills references the old subject. In one instance, the state even requires another subject which when moved leads to an invalid reference.

How could I implement proper move-semantics in this setup? Currently, I'm reserving enough space at the beginning so that moving is not necessary but this may not be feasible in the future.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have mentioned you are using a collection of Subjects, and Subject is not a polymorphic type in your code snippets. So are you referring to the move constructor for your State objects? I can see that you have defined a Copy constructor (albeit without a const reference parameter) in State which would prevent automatic generation of a move constructor and the compiler can't even use this copy constructor in place of the move constructor because the parameter is not a const reference. So ideally you should get a compiler error when you use move semantics

Comment: @MSSrikkanth Where did I define a copy constructor? I'm talking about the move-constructor of `Subject`.

Comment: Simple. Don't use reference members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since references cannot rebind in C++ any instance of a class with a reference member cannot be re-assigned properly unless the object one assigns from references the same object as the one assigned to. But as you want to be able to move the `Subject`s you need to be able to re-assign these members. There are two options here: You can either use pointers for the `subject_` and `target_` members or you can use `std::reference_wrapper`.

I personally prefer `std::reference_wrapper` because with pointers someone unfamiliar with the code might think that it could be a `nullptr`, wheras `reference_wrapper` makes it clear that the reference is always valid. However, in contrast to pointers, `std::reference_wrapper` requires that the referenced type is a complete type until C++20, so a forward declaration alone is not sufficient and you need to swap the definitions of `State` and `Subject` in you code in order to use it (as you can see at the very end of this answer).

Using `std::reference_wrapper` changes your `State` classes to something like this (Note I also added the missing assignment of `Subject::state_` in the constructor of `State`):

```
class State {
public:
    State(Subject& s)
     : subject_{std::ref(s)} {
        s.state_ = this;
    }
    State(State const&) = delete;
    State(State&&) = delete;
    State& operator=(State const&) = delete;
    State& operator=(State&&) = delete;
    virtual ~State() = default;

    virtual void doStuff() = 0;

protected:
    Subject& subject() {
      return subject_;
    }

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<Subject> subject_;
};

class StateA : public State {
public: 
    StateA(Subject& s, Subject& target)
      : State(s),
        target_{std::ref(target)} {
    }

    void doStuff() override { /* implementation requiring subject() */ }  

private:
    Subject& target() {
        return target_;
    }

    std::reference_wrapper<Subject> target_;
};
```

But as you also pointed out, when you move the `Subject` you need to inform the `State` object that the `Subject` as moved in order to adjust the now dangling reference `subject_`. However, not only do you need to notify the `State` class to reassign the `subject_` member, the `StateA` class additionally needs to update the `target_` data member when that instance of `Subject` is moved.

Since I assume you don't want to introduce a coupling where the `Subject` needs to know about all `State` subclasses that have additional references to `Subject`s just like `StateA` we thus need a generic notification mechanism so that the concrete (sub-)class of `State` can reassign the appropriate `reference_wrapper` members. My idea is to have the `State` register a callback that the `Subject` calls when it was moved. To do so I'd use a `std::function`. This changes the `Subject` class to something like this:

```
class Subject {
public:
    Subject() = default;
    Subject(Subject const&) = delete;
    Subject(Subject&& other)
      : state_{std::move(other.state_)},
        move_callbacks_{std::move(other.move_callbacks_)} {
        for (auto& callback : move_callbacks_) {
            callback(this);
        }
    }
    Subject& operator=(Subject const&) = delete;
    Subject& operator=(Subject&& other) {
        state_ = std::move(other.state_);
        move_callbacks_ = std::move(other.move_callbacks_);
        for (auto& callback : move_callbacks_) {
            callback(this);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~Subject() = default;

    void doStuff() { state_->doStuff(); }

    State* state_ = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::function<void(Subject*)>> move_callbacks_;
};
```

Of course we need to also modify the `State` and `StateA` constructors to register the correct callback:

```
State::State(Subject& s)
  : subject_{std::ref(s)} {
    s.state_ = this;
    s.move_callbacks_.emplace_back([this](Subject* new_location) { 
        subject_ = std::ref(*new_location); 
    });
}

StateA::StateA(Subject& s, Subject& target)
  : State(s),
    target_{std::ref(target)} {
    target.move_callbacks_.emplace_back([this](Subject* new_location) {
        target_ = std::ref(*new_location);
    });
}
```

After reordering everything so that it compiles we end up with

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

class State;

class Subject {
public:
    Subject() = default;
    Subject(Subject const&) = delete;
    Subject(Subject&& other)
      : state_{std::move(other.state_)},
        move_callbacks_{std::move(other.move_callbacks_)} {
        for (auto& callback : move_callbacks_) {
            callback(this);
        }
    }
    Subject& operator=(Subject const&) = delete;
    Subject& operator=(Subject&& other) {
        state_ = std::move(other.state_);
        move_callbacks_ = std::move(other.move_callbacks_);
        for (auto& callback : move_callbacks_) {
            callback(this);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~Subject() = default;

    void doStuff();

    State* state_ = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::function<void(Subject*)>> move_callbacks_;
};

class State {
public:
    State(Subject& s)
     : subject_{std::ref(s)} {
       s.state_ = this;
       s.move_callbacks_.emplace_back([this](Subject* new_location) { 
           subject_ = std::ref(*new_location); 
       });
    }
    State(State const&) = delete;
    State(State&&) = delete;
    State& operator=(State const&) = delete;
    State& operator=(State&&) = delete;
    virtual ~State() = default;

    virtual void doStuff() = 0;

protected:
    Subject& subject() {
      return subject_;
    }

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<Subject> subject_;
};

class StateA : public State {
public: 
    StateA(Subject& s, Subject& target)
      : State(s),
        target_{std::ref(target)} {
        target.move_callbacks_.emplace_back([this](Subject* new_location) {
            target_ = std::ref(*new_location);
        });
    }

    void doStuff() override { /* implementation requiring subject() */ }  

private:
    Subject& target() {
        return target_;
    }

    std::reference_wrapper<Subject> target_;
};

void Subject::doStuff() {
    assert(state_ && "Can't call `Subject::doStuff` on a `Subject` that"
                     "doesn't have an associated state!");
    state_->doStuff(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `reference_wrapper`. It seems like a good alternative to raw pointers. Unfortunately `target_` has a state itself. So one single `move_callback_` is not sufficient. I think, there is no way around some kind of Observer Pattern then and store a list of "on-move-subscribers". I just thought of using a different data structure like `std::list` that doesn't involve any move operations. But I will have to investigate that further.

Comment: @Albjenow What do you mean with "`target_` has a state itself?" Can one `Subject` be both the `subject_` of one state and the `target_` of another state? If not then the code above works fine because the constructor of `State` that is called by the constructor of `StateA` also registers the `subject_` callback.

Comment: @Albjenow I've extended my answer to allow multiple callbacks, now it works even when the `subject_` of one `State` is the `target_` of another.